# Parallel data processing confuses some information

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am trying to develop an application with some parallel data processing and the use of MySQL. Here is a piece of code where I ran into a problem

```
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Info> GetDatabaseForCurrentDay(System.DateTime day)
    {
        string[] date = day.ToShortDateString().Split('.');
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE Date ='" + date[2] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[0] + "';";
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, Info> info = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Info>();
        Info[] dayInfo = null;
        Parallel.ForEach(ReadData(ConnectionString, sqlQuery), data =>
        {
            int num = 2;
            string[] dataPieces = data.Split(new char[] { ',' }, num);
            FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<Info> engine = new FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<Info>();
            dayInfo = engine.ReadString(dataPieces[1], int.MaxValue);
            info.TryAdd(dataPieces[0], dayInfo[0]);
        });       
        return info;
    }
```

Apart from this fragment, the function `ReadData(ConnectionString, sqlQuery)` is also worth being mentioned, since it provides an argument for the loop `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> ReadData(string connectionString, string queryString)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(queryString, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string command2 = "USE testdatabase;";
                MySqlCommand commandUse = new MySqlCommand(command2, conn);
                commandUse.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comm.CommandTimeout = 0;
                MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append(reader.GetString(0) + ",");
                        sb.Append(reader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ",");
                        sb.Append(reader.GetDouble(2).ToString().Replace(',', '.') + ",");
                        sb.Append(reader.GetDouble(3).ToString().Replace(',', '.') + ",");
                        sb.Append(reader.GetDouble(4).ToString().Replace(',', '.') + ",");
                        sb.Append(reader.GetDouble(5).ToString().Replace(',', '.') + ",");
                        sb.Append(reader.GetUInt64(6) + ",");
                        sb.Append(reader.GetDouble(7).ToString().Replace(',', '.'));
                        yield return sb.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, let us move back to the problem. The code compiles and works, but the results it returns are incorrect. I noticed that `ConcurrentDictionary`contains keys with wrong values -- in a nutshell, `info.TryAdd(dataPieces[0], dayInfo[0])` may insert a key from one thread and the value from another thread and, therefore, the data may be corrupted. I understand that this behaviour is the setback of the parallel processing, but this method can't be omitted. I tried different ways to fix this problem, but nothing worked, and the data was still wrong. Are there any solutions to this problem which maintain the speed of execution for this code and save the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move `dayInfo`into your parallel for loop.  Basically this is a shared variable that keeps getting written over by each of the tasks giving you garbage results.  If you put it into the delegate, then it will be a different private variable for each iteration and not get clobbered:

```
// Info[] dayInfo = null;   <--Remove this
Parallel.ForEach(ReadData(ConnectionString, sqlQuery), data =>
{
    int num = 2;
    string[] dataPieces = data.Split(new char[] { ',' }, num);
    FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<Info> engine = new FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<Info>();

    //declare dayInfo locally within this scope instead 
    var dayInfo = engine.ReadString(dataPieces[1], int.MaxValue);
    info.TryAdd(dataPieces[0], dayInfo[0]);
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify: how exactly to get that data from the loop scope? If I use a delegate, won't it be another copy of the same problem?

Comment: I mean that you should declare `dayInfo` within the existing delegate, just like you have done with `dataPieces`, to keep it local to that scope.

Comment: Update answer with snippet of modified code.  Also, I wanted to clarify, that the reference to `dayInfo` keeps getting overwritten with a new array every time-- not the values within the same instance of `Info[]`.  Changing the code as I have described does not create more or less instances of `Info[]`, but rather keeps the reference to the new `Info[]` variables separate.

Comment: @Tim "Update answer with..." Git commit message detected!  :P